# What is the difference between directly casting an array or using System.Linq.Cast?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, casting, enumerable

Suppose I have 2 classes, `A` and `B`, and `B` can be cast to `A`. I declared an array of type `B[]` called `b`. Then if I wanted to cast `b` to `A[]`, what's the difference between `(A[])b` and `b.Cast<A>()`?

Comment: The first one will give you an array the second would be `IEnumerable<A>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two examples, while different, are both invalid.

You cannot cast an array of one object type to another, even if there exists a conversion operator between them (explicit or implicit). The compiler rightly prevents such a cast. The exception to this rule is if there exists an inheritance relationship; thanks to array covariance you can downcast to a base type (for reference types). The following works:

```
class A {} 
class B : A {} 

B[] bs = new[] { new B() };
A[] result = (A[])bs; // valid
```

See [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AGQEsoBHAbj1dwCEBtAXVICNSAXigBTAO6kuBbgG9RYgBQBKAL4tcAQR6kAhjqGkFW7kr7q2GUhpkrSxdJJDXbbIA=)

The same principles hold true for the `Cast<T>` method in LINQ--unless the types match, an exception will be thrown at runtime **upon enumeration**. The answer below is incorrect. You cannot, for example, `Cast` an array of `double` to `int`. Of course, if you don't enumerate the result (such as in the example) then no exception occurs. However upon actually enumerating (`foreach`, `ToList`, `ToArray`) an `InvalidCastException` will be thrown.

```
var array = new double[2];

array[0] = 10;
array[1] = 20;

var temp = array.Cast<int>(); // OK, not enumerated 
var converted = temp.ToList(); // bam! InvalidCastException
```

Notice the `temp` variable--as in the answer below it doesn't throw thanks to LINQ's deferred execution. It's once you enumerate it that it fails. See [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AGQEsoBHAbj2IIE4AKAIkB4NwEH3uASha48ANwCGYUtLCSAnqQC8pKAFMA7qTgB7CACMANuoDa6ALqi8cxacwWVpAplG2Fpgo9VZruKTLA6gC2AA5O7pQAwpIAzsAAPPTAAHycIhLSpADGulDi6mBBcE5BYZQAKrp08el+QA==).

The `Cast` method was designed to bridge the gap with pre-generic collections where values were stored internally as an array of `object` and the collections themselves only implement `IEnumerable`. `Cast` allows one to convert to `IEnumerable<T>`, however no casting/converting other than from `object` to the original type is allowed.

For structs this is obvious--a boxed `double` can only be unboxed to a `double`; it cannot be unboxed to an `int`. Take the simple, non-array case:

```
double d = 1.5;
object o = d;
int iOk = (int)(double)o; // ok
int iBad = (int)o; // fails
```

See [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AGQEsoBHAbj2IIE4AKAIkB4NwEH3uASha48pCaTgB7CACMANgFMppALykqAVlGTS0uQCslAY2D71U3ZPrnaAeQDWlzraGcZ85UOlNSAen99R3EbKDsAIQBDOBc3XwCggDMo2gUAZyA)

It makes sense then, that `Cast<int>` will fail as the method only inserts the single cast to `int`, and *not* the intermediate cast to `double` that would otherwise be required.

For classes, again `Cast` will only insert the direct cast. The method is generic and does not/cannot account for any user defined operators. So when you say you "have two classes that can be cast to each other" this still would not matter. In other words, the following will fail:

```
class A {} 
class B {
    public static implicit operator A(B b) => new A();
} 

B[] bs = new[] { new B() };
var temp = bs.Cast<A>(); // OK, not yet enumerated
A[] result = temp.ToArray(); // throws InvalidCastException
```

See [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AGQEsoBHAbj1dwCEBtAXVICNSAXigBTAO6kuBbgG9RYgBQBKAL4tcbPpQDCAQwDOwADwBBAHzLKAFQD2dQ8vVsMpEzJWli6STLyl/5ADM5AQAbKQiAB4ADgA2tADGtMCkNtEiYLrANmCuCuz8SkJm8sqk6h5sQA===)

Again (as above), the exception to this rule is if there exists an inheritance relationship between the two classes. You *can* downcast from one to the other:

```
class A {} 
class B : A {} 

B[] bs = new[] { new B() };
A[] result = bs.Cast<A>().ToArray(); // valid
```

See [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AGQEsoBHAbj1dwCEBtAXVICNSAXigBTAO6kuBbgG9RYgBQBKAL4tcbPpQDCAQwDOwADwBBAHzLKAFQD2dQ8vVsMpEzJWli6SSDce2QA===)

One alternative is to use LINQ's `Select` to project your original collection, applying the conversion operators you desire:

```
class A {} 
class B {
    public static implicit operator A(B b) => new A();
} 

B[] bs = new[] { new B() };
A[] result = bs.Select(b => (A)b).ToArray(); // valid!
```

See [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AGQEsoBHAbjzwCEBtAXVICMBnUgF5SUAKYB3bqQDeoyaTYAKAJSkAvi1wBBaWDH8IAG2DC+/SgGUxRsQGNgS3sIB8pJdpW8VlACoB7bTAwAEMAT1UmUgB6aNIANxCjWjgAQlJWXAAzf30QuwALJUSwUhDSelJ9QxM1PFIG8gIATiUQlS1MjFJtWXUM/HRFWXqG1ABmJoA2CoBbAAdku1pTf3mxUOBcnqU2PjUhN3EJHY68fqA=). This would also work in the case of the `double`/`int`:

```
var array = new double[] { 10.2, 20.4 };
int[] result = array.Select(d => (int)d).ToArray();
```

See [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AGQEsoBHAbjzwDcBDMUrsDgT1IBeUlACmAd1JwA9hABGAGzEBtALqkA3qQKZK6GKSyUALKQC+LXPWDrSYMQGcIi4MJ5g+/SgGUxygGNgAAo4YQA+UmCbAEo4GMoAFRkAQU8BYJirPAAzGQcOAIALYM5uDlJ6eycXYBjSPFIm8gIATmCOLLwgA=)

Comment: Is it because in the source code of `Cast`, it iterates the elements in the original collection like `foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj;`  so even if there's a conversion operator, it will still fail because the elements are being iterated as `object`s?

Comment: No. It's because the generic cast `(TResult)obj` is... *generic*. It doesn't know about user defined casts. Casts are methods underneath and require the compiler to insert a call to them at the cast site. But since it's a generic method the compiler has no way to know what that would actually be. The underlying code of the method doesn't magically change because the generic arguments do, so how could the appropriate static method call for an arbitrary TResult be inserted in? It can't.

Answer (score 3):

These are two different things.

**Language casting**

`(A[])b` cast `b` to type `A[]` and does not compile or throws an exception at runtime if `b` is not type of `A[]`.

Take for example the case of doubles and integers:

```
var array = new object[2];

array[0] = 10.2;
array[1] = 20.8;

var casted = (int[])array; // does not compile here,
                           // or throw an exception at runtime if types mismatch
```

Here we just cast a type to another, no matter what they are, collection or not.

[Casting and type conversions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)

**Linq Cast**

`Cast<TResult>` convert each items of an `IEnumerable` to `TResult`.

It's just a LINQ loop already written to make our life easier over *boxed* values.

[Enumerable.Cast(IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast)

> Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type.

*From the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,27bb217a6d5457ec,references)*

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source)
{
  foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj;
}
```

Thus this method can be used to unbox boxed values from a collection like `Rows` of a `DataGridView` or any similar "reduced" collections like for example `Items` in a `ListBox` or a `ComboBox`.

That means that the type of the items must be type of `TResult` or ancestor.

*Example*

```
var array = new object[2];

array[0] = 10.2;
array[1] = 20.8;

var converted = array.Cast<int>(); // compiles but will not work
                                   // and throw an InvalidCastException
```

*Note*

Because of the yielding, `Cast` method is deferred, so we get the result only when it is executed, for example using `foreach` or `ToList`.

[Deferred Execution of LINQ Query](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution)

[Deferred Vs Immediate Query Execution in LINQ](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/deferred-vs-immediate-query-execution-in-linq/)

[Deferred execution and lazy evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-lazy-evaluation)

**Alternative to solve the problem on the sample**

Therefore to convert the array, we can use a direct cast using for example a `foreach` or `Select`:

```
var converted = array.Select(v => (int)v).ToArray(); // get int[]

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, converted));

> 10
> 20
```

*Using an extension method*

```
static public class EnumerableHelper
{
  static public IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    where TSource : IConvertible
  {
    foreach ( TSource obj in source )
      yield return (TResult)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(TResult));
  }
}

var converted = array.Cast<double, int>();

> 10
> 21
```

Also `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to avoid problems on numbers, as well as a formatter to avoid roundings.

Comment: The extension method presented will only work for primitive types and/or types that implement `IConvertible` (required by `Convert.ChangeType`). For the OP's assertion that they have "two classes" this approach is very unlikely to work. If their classes don't implement `IConvertible` then `ChangeType` will throw (unless the target type is the same as the source)... And if they do go through the gymnastics of implementing `IConvertible` (all 17 methods!!) they would have to special case `IConvertible.ToType` to account for each possible type they'd want to support *conversion to*. Not fun!

Answer (score 2):

`.Cast<T>` is from Linq. It will enumerate the collection casting each item to `T` and creating a new sequent. The other is an explicit cast, telling the compiler you would want to access the original as that type.

Comment: So by using `Cast<T>` the type to cast to can be determined at runtime while casting directly can't?

Comment: `Cast<>`, despite its name does not perform any inplicit or explicit casts. It is meant for use with pre-generic collections where everything was stored as an `object`. It will cast the items from `object` to the type specified. However, upon enumeration unless the values are the **exact same type** (for structs) or have an *inheritance relationship* (for classes) the "cast" will fail and throw an `InvalidCastException`